# Java Play Framework Localization in AJAX calls

Tags: java, ajax, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to localize messages in Java PlayFramework 2.2.0 in AJAX calls ?

Now I am make calls and hardcode messages (@Mesages("message-id")(lang)) by checking of the languages used per a page, but I am pretty sure there is a better way to do it.

Thanks in advance, 
Simeon

Comment: Can you show us real case ? I'm not sure if I understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to do seems to be impossible, as your code is trying to get the data from Message file in configs which is done at the time of rendering that view. So scala is compiled on server side and you are trying to make the request for particular message in AJAX which is javascript code and client side execution.

Alternate solution for this is create an Post api for it which takes message-id as parameter and returns data from message file in configs through ajax call.